# Can i apply different stylesheets in phonegap

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, phonegap-build

Am storing a stylesheet(CSS File) from the webserver into device storage using the file system [phonegap guide for File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File). From the device storage i want to apply the stylesheet in my app. Here i will update the stored stylesheet often. In that case,

My Doubts are,

1. As my app will be in .apk format, How my application will call stylesheet from device storage?
2. If am defining a standard path in my html say `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />` Will the storage path of the stylesheet `css/stylesheet.css` differs from one mobile device to another device (say iphone and android devices)?

Answer (score 1):

**For your first query**

In local storage means you can create a seprate folder named as css and yes you can use multiple css modifying any of them is in your hands.

**For your second query**

No it will be same.Means the hierarchy under asset folder it will be same.

See I am talking about this hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: what am doing is am calling the css from web server and storing it in local storage. often my css may gets update from server(overwritten). In that case how my apk file will know about css file

Comment: @sabarish by local storage what do you mean local folder or local storage which phone gap provides.

Comment: Ok, I make you better understanding am getting a css file from web server and storing it as file in phone using this guide <link>http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File</link>. Now i will get the local path of the css file(from device where the file is written). If i apply this to my .apk file will it executes or not?

Comment: @sabrish ya it will execute try it.

Comment: ok let me try it and for second query, when am storing the file in device it gives me a local path of stored file, in that case will the path differs from one device to another